# How do I capture bank account name, number, branch code, etc. in checkout for offline processing?

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways

The [Commerce Bank Transfer](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bank_transfer) module [claims this is part of Commerce 2.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bank_transfer/issues/2891395), but I am not sure how to accomplish it. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "creating a manual payment gateway" in Commerce 2.

Unfortunately, the [docs page is blank](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/payments/create-payment-gateway/manual-gateways).

So, here's how I set up bank transfer payment collection for Japan.

1. Create a new payment gateway at `/admin/commerce/config/payment-gateways/add`.
2. Set the **Plugin** to **Manual**.
3. Fill in the rest of the info as needed for your setup.
4. Continue to configure your store in Commerce, and use the manual payment gateway (with any other payment gateways you require-- for example, I give users the option of bank transfer or credit card via Stripe).

Comment: Thanks, @Patrick. But that works partly. Essentially the customer needs to enter their Bank Account Name, Account number, Branch code, etc. during the checkout. The same needs to be stored along with the order for the admin to do the offline processing.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that; in my case, I didn't need to store any info.  There is an [open feature request for adding extra fields for payment gateways to collect](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2894961), but that issue hasn't seen any action for quite awhile, so maybe a different solution has been developed.